# Migrate wireless settings from xp to windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, migration

I'm trying to migrate the settings of my old machine (Win XP Professional) to the new one (Win 7 Professional) and I would like to keep my saved passwords for various wireless networks. How can I export them from XP and import in Win7?

A few things that are mentioned a lot in chat groups but don't work:

- netsh can export/import wlan profiles on Vista/Win7, but not on XP;
- the Wireless Network Setup Wizard can only export settings for networks created by me;
- the best method I found was via [WirelessKeyView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html) which can list hex keys, but cannot load them nor save them in a useful format; I would rather not copy them one-by-one by hand.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the User State Migration Tool or the Files and Settings Transfer Wizard?

These are both MS tools, the FaSTW is included in XP and 7 and I've used it for transfer between both.

I've not used the USMT myself, it's more for business environments, as I understand it.

The FaSTW has the ability to select, on a pretty granular level, what you want to backup and copy, and it supports creating a single archive, direct network copy, as well as several other functions. I've found it decently fast and capable when migrating multi-gigabyte user profiles with all their various settings between machines in my home network.

Answer (score 0):

This won't do exactly what you want but it will give you a list to dump from with XP. Try [WirelessKeyView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html). It will list all of the saved networks+passwords and allow you to dump that to a txt, html or xml.

Comment: Yes, WirelessKeyView comes closest, as I said in the question (except I messed up the link formatting), but none of its save formats are particularly useful, and it cannot read its own dumps.

Comment: The problem with this is that Windows XP only stores the binary key (as opposed to the passphrase, which is the text that you have to enter when connecting) for WPA networks. While that should be enough to connect to the network, I don't know how to set it as Windows 7 also asks for the passphrase.